# Save SQL result to variable

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to save SQL result in variable and then use that to echo data anywhere on my site.

for example

```
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

and then use that variable to show that data anywhere else on site and even repeat it in some loop

```
$show=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```

I tried that in for while loop and it echo my result only once.

my full code

```
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$r=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table2");
while($x=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
{
       echo $x["ID"];
       while( $show=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {echo $show["ID"];}
}
```

Comment: Pasting also the loop code may be helpful

Comment: Yes, we need the faulty code to help you

Comment: what is this guys? SO is for mind readers get with it

Comment: the outer echo is for table2, the inner echo is for table, and after the first time thru the inner fetch_assoc, the pointer will be at the end of result set and will never output the inner echo of table (a second time) because the query is run once outside of both while loops. so once and done

Answer (score 0):

Make a `$table1_array` and a `$table2_array` and instead of `echo $x` use `$table1_array[] = $x`. Since the table2 - select needs nothing from table1 you should read it only once. Make no inner loop, make two separate loops.

EDIT:

to clarify:

```
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$table_array = array();

while( $show=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $table_array[] = $show;
}
$r=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table2");
while($x=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    echo $x["ID"];
    foreach($table_array as $show){
        echo $show["ID"];
    }      
}
```

Comment: problem is that I have to show data from table1 while reading and showing data from table2